# "Begging for votes" vs. "Reminding for upvotes" vs. "Reminding for acceptance"

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, accepted-answer

**Are ["Begging for votes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63439/232130) and "Reminding for upvotes" equivalent?**

If so, and given that "Begging for votes" (="Reminding for upvotes", assumed) is generally [looked down upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63440/232130) then a second question is brought.

I wonder why some find annoying that others try to help the community by a reminder for an upvote in [*any* case without distinction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63440/232130). Moreover, I wonder why they find it more annoying than a comparable reminder for accepting an answer, which [seems to be ok](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/232130). The two look very similar to me. The interest behind any of these may be reputation with helping as a side effect, or helping with reputation as a side effect. And in any of the two cases, with or without technical merit, that is a completely separate issue. So,

**What is the explanation for this differentiated perception?**

I wouldn’t dare judging intentions, in general, and in particular if the outcome is useful for the community, and the inquiry is respectful. Some of these reminders may easily not fit the [definition of rep-whoring: Stack Overflow users who post questions or answers for the sole benefit of accumulating as many reputation points as possible, without regard to the technical merit or the contribution to the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19522/232130), and this is probably the cause of [some acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/232130).

PS: I found some questions that are *[re](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85562/232130)[la](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176113/232130)[ted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/232130)* to this one, but none that seemed a possible duplicate.

**EDIT**

PS2: I do have an opinion ([made explicit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207071/232130)), but I am looking for answers (whatever they may be) to the specific questions asked, so they would be useful for the community (including myself), to separate the wheat from the chaff. I take an answer that addresses the questions and clarifies as useful (even in dissent).

Comment: Part of the motivation is my perception of a strong focus on potential rep-whoring. This can be discussed, but the worst part is that this comes with an associated loss of focus on the service of SO to the community (i.e., you, me...)

Comment: Upvote. Reminding for upvotes is NOT "begging" or even "whoring". Too many good answers here never get an upvote. I know that rep points can not be eaten, but they are a kind of acknowledgment.

Answer (score 19):

As with most questions of etiquette, it depends largely on the situation. Think of it like a waiter asking for a tip vs. informing a tourist that it is customary to tip waiters in the region.

In the first case it seems a bit presumptuous, perhaps the waiter wasn't very good and didn't really deserve a tip, or perhaps the waiter was good but the customer was offended at the implication that they wouldn't leave a tip. In either case a good waiter knows not to ask. If the customer is familiar with the custom and was happy with the service they'll tip as they see fit.

In the other case, say you had a friend visiting from overseas who wasn't familiar with the custom, it may be appropriate for you to inform your friend of the custom, but not to press him or her with any expectation that a tip must be left. If it were me, I would probably politely and quietly leave a tip for them.

What has all that got to do with voting?

Asking for up votes is a bit like the waiter who asks for a tip. People will likely not respond or they may even respond negatively, just because they were asked.

Informing people about how the vote/accept system works is a bit more like telling your tourist friend about the custom. It should never be done with the tone that they must do anything and in most cases its probably better to just drop an upvote on the answer you like rather than telling them to do so.

If the answer in question belongs to you, you're much more likely to be seen as the presumptuous waiter than the informative friend. If you get a "thanks that works great" type comment it may be seen as appropriate, by some, to inform a new user about the custom of accepting an answer, but pushing for an upvote as well is pushing your luck.

**Asking for an upvote is more like a waiter seeing the tip on the table and chasing down the customer to tell them that it wasn't enough, which is likely considered rude in most all regions.**

If your service was really that good the community will eventually leave a good tip.

Comment: I understand this interesting answer, but I think it's too generic, and I do not not see how it is an answer to any of the two specific questions. Moreover, I wonder what the analogues of "Begging for votes", "Reminding for upvotes", "Reminding for acceptance", and the rating of answers in terms of upvotes/acceptance would be in your example.

Comment: @sancho.s "begging for votes" or "Reminding for upvotes" = "Rude Waiter"... "Reminding for acceptance" can be appropriate in some situations, but usually best heard from a helpful third party...

Comment: I'll admit the analogy isn't perfect, but I think the etiquette involved is similar

Comment: @apaul34208 Actually, I think that was a perfect analogy. Very fitting, great answer.

Comment: @sancho.s There is a difference between begging, and informing users. It is frowned upon to beg for votes or acceptance in basically all situations. However, if you are merely informing a user how the system works, I don't see an issue - especially if the answer was helpful and they are looking for a way to thank you. [As said by Bill](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat/14999#14999)

Comment: @JoshC I think he was looking to support an existing notion http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207071/217863

Comment: Good answer. If user comments "great answer, solved my issue", informing him he could express it with upvote and acceptance is a bit like waiter who, hearing "thank you for perfect service" asks would you maybe like to leave a tip. Especially with credit card payment when tip amount must be processed by card reader - there is an electronic excuse to ask without sounding insistent. Just like with votes and accept tick.

Comment: @apaul34208 : I was not looking for any support or specific answer. I do have an opinion (made explicit), but I was looking for answers (whatever they may be) to the questions asked, so they would be useful for the community (including myself), to separate the wheat from the chaff. Sadly, there exists the possibility of delivering undercover messages (this was never my point), and everyone is free to think he catched one. This is another way of placing effort where it does not best serve us users. As for the analogue, the questions got buried beneath a good answer (for another question).

Comment: @JoshC : I was only looking for answers...

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of  “Reminding for upvotes” might just be my idea of “Begging for votes."  If you ask someone who's been around the block a few times to upvote you, it just gets painted differently.

I really wish everyone would assume that everyone else knows exactly how the system work, then to focus on the meat of Stack - answers.

Overall though, [apaul34208](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208134/164243)'s answer is perfect. Upvotes really *are* tips. Heck, nobody owes me anything and I personally consider the 15 points for an accepted to be a tip too.

Comment: This is an answer (kind of "most likely, Yes") to question 1. My answer to that question is "No", but I value the fact that you targeted the question. +1 for "This answer is useful". Thanks.